# Exclude venv from HTML coverage export in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, coverage.py

After running all my tests with coverage on PyCharm, I need to export coverage report as html. When I do this, the entire venv folder is included even though it is marked to be excluded in the project structure, which of course is not desired.

Is there a way to exclude it from the report?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to use the coverage.py `include` option to only include your project's code. It will make your tests run faster if you avoid measuring the coverage of venv in the first place.